# SocketException (SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = 192.168.100.21, port = 48094)

Tags: flutter, xampp

I am getting this error. I have change port 80 to 8080 and 443 to 1443 to run it but still didn't work. Do anyone have an idea how to fix this error. For the first time, it worked but after a windows update, it's not working already change many ports still facing the same issue.

Comment: Are you facing the issue while starting XAMPP or running app?

Comment: Facing this issue while running app

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem? When are you facing this issue? What's the exact error?

Comment: I am trying to run my flutter app connecting the database with my app. When I started on my project it's working but after that windows updation start. After WIndow has updated It's not working and showing this error "SocketException (SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = 192.168.100.21, port = 48094)"

Comment: I have tried many other ports to fix it but still facing the same error. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Are you running back-end locally? Are you running app in emulator ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214053/discussion-between-ruhma-ch-and-sanjay-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

If your Flutter app is trying to connect to the localhost, the IP address might've been changed if the machine uses a dynamic IP address. Check if the IP address of the machine has changed after the update causing for the SocketException error to be thrown. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779992) might help you out.